# InnerJoin vs Contains, which is faster

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am writing query to find sum of the integer value from database using linq. while developing I got two thoughts in my mind. I can either do it by contains or inner join. Following are the queries

```
var Customer = db.tbl_User_to_CustomerMast.Where(i => i.fk_Store_ID == s.ShopID).ToList();
```

Query 1:

```
var RewardCount = db.tbl_RewardAwardMast.Where(i => Customer.Select(j => j.User_Customer_ID).ToList().Contains(i.fk_Customer_UserID.Value)).Sum(i => i.RewardPoints).GetValueOrDefault(0);
```

Query 2:

```
var RewardCount = Customer.Join(db.tbl_RewardAwardMast, i => i.User_Customer_ID, j => j.fk_Customer_UserID, (i, j) => new { Customer = i, Reward = j }).Sum(i=>i.Reward.RewardPoints).GetValueOrDefault(0);
```

I know that in both queries calculation will be done on the server side for matching the records.

So which query is suitable for faster execution?

Comment: Why don't you profile your code to find out? Repeat both queries like 1 million times each, and measure the total execution time in each case.

Comment: You mean I should put the both queries in for loop for large number of repeatation? will it give me correct result? I've never tried it before

Comment: I suggest you look at the SQL generated, too - it may well be exactly the same. This would be very different to doing the same thing in LINQ to Objects.

Comment: Yes, use a simple for loop and use [the Stopwatch class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) to measure the execution time.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that Query 1 will be faster as it will be translated simple SQL similar to this:

```
SELECT SUM(RewardPoints)
FROM User_to_CustomerMast
WHERE fk_Customer_UserID IN (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,...,cx)
```

Query 2 might be slower because you are essentially trying to join local list variable with data from DB. It does not matter that this list originally came from DB, this association with DB is lost when doing `ToList()`. To execute such query, necessary information will be passed to DB to generate second table so there is something to `JOIN` existing table with. This will be done using UNION.

```
SELECT SUM(RewardPoints)
FROM 
    User_to_CustomerMast INNER JOIN
    (
         SELECT c1
         UNION 
         SELECT c2
         UNION 
         SELECT c3
         UNION 
         SELECT c4
         UNION 
         SELECT c5
         UNION 
         ...
         ...
         SELECT cx
     ) AS T ON T.Id = fk_Customer_UserID
```

As you can see, query expands fast when local list grows. If your list is too long, at one point you might even get exception that SQL is too complex.

You can see detailed analysis on this topic here:
http://blog.hompus.nl/2010/08/26/joining-an-iqueryable-with-an-ienumerable/