# Get all entities from DbSet<TEntity> with a property value that is in an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

This seems like it would be really simple, but I cannot seem to resolve it. Using EF Core, I have a `DbSet<Rule> Rules` in my `DbContext`.

```
public class Rule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Raw { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to write a query where, given an `IEnumerable<string> lines`, give me all of the `Rule`s from the `DbSet` where its `Raw` value is an element in `lines` (exact match, not a substring of a value).

For some time, I was using something like:

```
private IQueryable<Rule> GetExistingRules() =>
    dbContext.Rules.Where(r => lines.Contains(r.Raw));
```

But, I have since discovered that (I think) this was not doing what I was expecting. (This method is immediately followed by inserting new `Rule`s for all elements of `lines` that do not currently exist. I was getting duplicate `Rule`s with the same `Raw` value...) I think, instead, I need to use `.Intersect()`?

I tried using a custom EqualityComparer per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10633506/2343739), but it throws an exception.

```
    private IQueryable<Rule> GetExistingRules()
    {
        var lineRules = lines.Select(l => new Rule {Raw = l});
        return dbContext.Rules.Intersect(lineRules, new RuleRawEqualityComparer());
    }

    private class RuleRawEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Rule>
    {
        public bool Equals(Rule x, Rule y) => x?.Raw == y?.Raw;
        ...
    }
```

> Could not parse expression
>   'value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[FilterLists.Data.Entities.Rule]).Intersect(__p_0,
>   __p_1)': This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.Intersect' is currently not supported.

What is the best way to compose this query? Note that it is in a chain of `DbContext` interactions, so I'd prefer to keep the return type as an `IQueryable` to enable EF's lazy query composition.

[Context on GitHub](https://github.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists/issues/357)

**Update:** More info on why I suspected the `Contains()` approach was not working:

This is the class where the query is being used. I am seeing exceptions like below because the `Raw` column in the database has a unique constraint. I thought my logic (use of `Except()` in `CreateNewRules()`) would prevent any rows in `Rules` with duplicate `Raw` values, but maybe my issue lies elsewhere...

```
public class SnapshotBatch
{
    private readonly FilterListsDbContext dbContext;
    private readonly IEnumerable<string> lines;
    private readonly Data.Entities.Snapshot snapEntity;

    public SnapshotBatch(FilterListsDbContext dbContext, IEnumerable<string> lines,
        Data.Entities.Snapshot snapEntity)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
        this.lines = lines;
        this.snapEntity = snapEntity;
    }

    public async Task SaveAsync()
    {
        var existingRules = GetExistingRules();
        var newRules = CreateNewRules(existingRules);
        dbContext.Rules.AddRange(newRules);
        var rules = existingRules.Concat(newRules);
        AddSnapshotRules(rules);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    private IQueryable<Rule> GetExistingRules() =>
        dbContext.Rules.Where(r => lines.Contains(r.Raw));

    private List<Rule> CreateNewRules(IQueryable<Rule> existingRules) =>
        lines.Except(existingRules.Select(r => r.Raw))
             .Select(r => new Rule {Raw = r})
             .ToList();

    private void AddSnapshotRules(IQueryable<Rule> rules) =>
        snapEntity.AddedSnapshotRules
                  .AddRange(rules.Select(r => new SnapshotRule {Rule = r}));
}
```

Snippet from exception StackTrace (where '###Meebo:AdElement.Root' is a sample value for `Raw` in the `Rules` table):

> FilterLists.Services.Snapshot.Snapshot.TrySaveAsync() in
>   /home/travis/build/collinbarrett/FilterLists/src/FilterLists.Services/Snapshot/Snapshot.cs:line
>   43 Duplicate entry '###Meebo:AdElement.Root' for key 'IX_rules_Raw' at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(ResultSet
>   resultSet) in
>   C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line
>   93 at

**Update 2**: I am fairly sure the issue I was seeing with `Contains()` was due to [this issue](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/667) that has an [active PR](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/pull/670). Because my strings have all kinds of special characters, I think they were not getting escaped properly when passed into `Contains()`, but they seem to be properly escaped as parameters in a `Join()`.

Comment: Can you explain again what's the problem with `Contains` approach (because it seem to be the correct way of getting existing rules from db)?

Comment: @IvanStoev See Update at the bottom of the question. It could be I'm asking the completely wrong question... I'm not sure.

Comment: The exception seem to be generated by a different code (`Snapshot.TrySaveAsync`). Most likely the problem is caused by  `snapEntity.AddedSnapshotRules.Add[Range]` - in case `snapEntity` is attached to a different context, it is possible that change tracker of that context can consider `Rule` objects being new.

Comment: `SnapshotBatch` uses the same `DbContext` instance as its caller `Snapshot.TrySaveAsync()`. However, since `Snapshot` spins up multiple instances of `SnapshotBatch`, I wonder if there are conflicts due to everything being async...

Comment: Note that the comparison in the database is probably case-insensitive. So if in the database you have rule `A` and `lines` contains `a` and `A` (or `a` only), you will get existing rules: `A`, lines except `A` is `a`, because C# is case-sensitive,  and you'll try to insert `a`, which is a duplicate for the database.

Comment: Thanks, @GertArnold . That's a good thought. I'm a bit out of the mainstream using MySQL with EF, I know, but I thought since my table uses `COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin` that my queries would be case-sensitive. But, maybe that is not the case? Will try some testing on that...

Comment: All, see "Update 2" in question. I think this whole issue had to do with character escaping. Still validating, but that theory seems initially to have been the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not forget that when you use linQ with EFCore and IQueryable, it translate the c# code in Sql statements.

Did you tried this ?

```
var query = from rule in dbContext.Rules
            join line in lines
                on rule.Raw equals line
            select rule;
```

Comment: Initial testing seems to show this working better than `.Contains()`, going to do more full testing which will take some time. I'm using the R#-converted method chain syntax `dbContext.Rules.Join(lines, rule => rule.Raw, line => line, (rule, line) => rule)`, but should be equivalent.

Comment: Wondering if `Join()` will work better than `Contains()` since I am dealing with large datasets per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40650720/performance-join-vs-contains-linq-to-entities#comment68534417_40651241)...

Comment: Though `Contains()` should work as well, marking this as accepted as a valid alternative that I am using at least until the issue mentioned in `Update 2` in my question is resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

> Give me all of the Rules from the DbSet where its Raw value is an element in lines (exact match etc.)

Your first solution will give the desired result:

```
var requestedRules = dbContext.Rules
   .Where(rule => lines.Contains(rule));
```

In words: from the collection of `Rules`, select only those `Rules` that have a `Raw` value that equals one of the values in the sequence of `lines`.

> I was getting duplicate Rules with the same Raw value...)

Well apparently your source collection has Rules with the same Raw value!

If you want only unique Raw values you'll have to decide what to do with duplicates:

```
Id  Raw
 1  "Hello"
 2  "Hello"
```

Which one do you want? The first? the last? Both? None? Any?

Let's go for Any: we'll make groups of Rules with same Raw value, and from every Group we take the first one (or if you want the last, after all we don't care. But that is a bit less efficient.

```
var result = dbContext.Rules
   .Where(rule => lines.Contains(rule))
   .GroupBy(rule => rule.Raw)
   .Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault());
```

In words: from the collection of `Rules`, select only those `Rules` that have a `Raw` value that equals one of the values in the sequence of `lines`. From the remaining elements make groups of Rules with same Raw value. Then from every Group take any element, for example the first one.

If you want all / only the first / only the last, you'll know what to do by now.

Comment: Thanks, Harald. Under "Update" in my question, I mentioned that "the `Raw` column in the database has a unique constraint". So, there aren't duplicate `Raw` values already in the database (as evidenced by the exception at the bottom of my question). I suspect that my issue has something to do with multiple instances of `SnapshotBatch` sharing `dbContext` running in `async` per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930802/get-all-entities-from-dbsettentity-with-a-property-value-that-is-in-an-ienumer#comment90813655_51930802).